# at least $2^{\frac{n}{2}}$ choices of the signs $+$ and $-$ such that $\pm x^{n} \pm x^{n-1} \pm \cdots \pm x <\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: inequality

> Let $n$ be an even positive integer. Prove that for any real number $x$ there are at least
> $2^{\frac{n}{2}}$ choices of the signs $+$ and $-$ such that
> $\pm x^{n} \pm x^{n-1} \pm \cdots \pm x <\frac{1}{2}$.

---

I tried doing this with induction. For base case of $n=2$, it's clearly true. Assuming it's true for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we have to prove it's true for $n+2$. So we have,$\pm x^{n} \pm x^{n-1} \pm \cdots \pm x <\frac{1}{2}$, thus $\pm x^{n+2} \pm x^{n+1} \leq 0$, but how do we do it?

Comment: @D.W. I think I have got his point and got the solution,so i guess there's no need of that. Maybe I should close the post (depending on possible responses)

Comment: @zaemon_23, Questions exist not just for you -- our mission is to build up an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others in the future, in the format of high-quality questions and answers.  So I hope you won't close the question.  (And in the future, you can think about how to write your question so it is most easily findable by others with the same question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a+b=−(−a−b)$ and $a−b=−(−a+b)$, so one of each pair is not positive. This gives that at least 2 of the 4 new possibilities are nonpositive.

This allows two ways of assigning $+,−$ to the new terms and combine both of them with all of the original terms giving $2\times 2^{n/2}$ possibilities.